# Build a Talend job to generate email alerts

Tags: talend

I have data stored in a postgressql database. I want to create a Talend job to check rules on this data and in case of non-satisfaction of these rules, an email alert is generated with the tsendmail component. How to configure context variables containing subject and email text which will be changed depending on the alert?. What components to use?

I tried to do this with a java script on the tjava component, but this component cannot use input_rows to check conditions. Also, with tjavaRow I cannot create context variables and use them.

Comment: Look at `globalMap.put()`, that will help you.  Unfortunately though, given you've provided nothing re: an attempt, it's too hard to help.

Comment: like Skin said look at globalMap.put() but if you need input_rows or your variables depends on an input look at the tJavaFlex (or tJavaRow)